# Best way to test desktop environments

Tags: desktop-environments

Note: This question is not asking for a "best DE(desktop environment)", it is asking about easy ways to test multiple DEs.

I am going to install Ubuntu on my brother's laptop for the first time, and I need to find the right flavor for him. What would be a good way to test multiple flavors or DEs of Ubuntu on his laptop?

Right now my default is just to download a bunch of ISOs and live boot them individually. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your current method is the best way. Otherwise Create 5 partitions of around 8-9 GB and install each flavored Ubuntu. Test them and then keep one, delete others

Comment: Testing individual ISOs is the only way; if your brother's laptop has sufficient horsepower you might consider installing Virtual Box - this will eliminate the requirement of burning the ISOs to DVDs or flash drives. You can easily have 4 or 5 setup in short time.

Answer (score 1):

Just install an VM and test it there ;-)

Comment: Could you please expand your answer to explain how to do what you propose? The OP should not have to request clarification, and perhaps they don't know about VMs

Comment: I agree with Tobias, just use an Ubuntu VM in Virtualbox and install the different DEs to test which one you like without causing changes on your main system.

Comment: This question is mostly opinion based . Though VM is a right choice to test, but you have to consider the real hardware compatibility issue. VM can't emulate real performance of your hardware. Again, there can be constraints on Memory for OP.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to install the standard Ubuntu and then install a number of different desktops using `apt-get install <desktop-flavour>`.

See list of most common desktop flavours and install instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/65083/425630).

When you log in you can select the desktop flavour you want from a drop-down list and run it on the actual machine.

Once your're done, you can either remove the unwanted ones (`apt-get remove/purge <desktop-flavour>`) or reinstall Ubuntu with the desktop flavour(s) you want.